# how can I add a background image in vis.js in network

Tags: javascript, vis.js

My problem is how to set a background image when using the `visjs` network library. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vis/dist/vis.js"></script>
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

Comment: Could you explain in more details what your problem is and where you are having trouble?

Comment: like discussed here? https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1397

Answer (score 1):

Once the network is drawn, you can set the background image behind it by setting a style on the `canvas` used by the network. I'm using this:

```
var sourceCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
sourceCanvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('images.jpg')";
```

This is the effect:

[image]